# How can i add parameter in mandrill html text?

Tags: mandrill

Is there any way to include the parameter i html portion of mandrill ?

I am not using template.

here is my code.

```
 $mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR_API_KEY');
$message = array(
    'html' => '<p>here is my email</p>',
    'text' => 'Example text content',
    'subject' => 'example subject',
    'from_email' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
    'from_name' => 'Example Name',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'name' => 'Recipient Name',
            'type' => 'to'
        ),
         array(
            'email' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'name' => 'Recipient Name',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
```

What i want to do is to add a parameter to the html content.

```
 'html' => '<p>here is my email{ param}</p>', // this line
```

How can i do this  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking to use Mandrill merge tags.

You can insert merge tags into your HTML content and have it inject personalized information for each recipient. They can be used in your content with the format *|MERGETAG|* and by defining "merge_vars" in your message array.

Here's an example from their docs:

```
"message": {
        "global_merge_vars": [
            {
                "name": "var1",
                "content": "Global Value 1"
            }
        ],
        "merge_vars": [
            {
                "rcpt": "emailadress@domain.com",
                "vars": [
                    {
                        "name": "fname",
                        "content": "John"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "lname",
                        "content": "Smith"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
```

source:
http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21678522-How-do-I-use-merge-tags-to-add-dynamic-content-

In testing a bit, Mandrill actually supports a few merge tags "out of the box", so you should just be able to add *|EMAIL|* into your HTML content and it'll pull that email address in from your TO array.